# update-initramfs runs scripts in init-premount?

Tags: boot, initramfs

So,  I have a weird laptop that won't correctly boot from my USB3.0 stick. **Grub** and `initramfs` load up, but then miraculously the stick is not mounted. If I just wait, the machine drops to the busybox shell. `blkid` doesn't list my stick. But if I before that happens, at the correct time, replug that stick, Ubuntu boots up correctly.

So I thought, let's automate that. I got myself a restart_usb shell script, put it in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount`, and ran `update-initramfs -u`.

Now comes the funny part: the script is executed while generating the new `initramfs`, thus resetting usb and by that, leaving a running linux with no access to any of its partitions. Only hard reset helps there.

So my question is: how do I put a script that runs before we try to mount `/` into the `initramfs` without it being executed by `update-initramfs`?

Cheers.

Edit: I'm running a fresh install (not updated) of Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, so I poked around in other scripts included in `initramfs`.
Apparently, the "trick" is in a script header which should look like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 set -e

 case $1 in
 prereqs)
     prereqs
     exit 0
     ;;
 esac
```

The `case` statement is the important part.

It is mentioned in [this documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html), but it doesn't state that you have to include this header even if you do not require precise ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```